# A man moving along the edge of a cube with probabilities

Tags: probability

A man stands at one corner of a cube. By travelling across the edges of the cube the man moves. At each corner there are 3 options to which edge he will walk along. Let corner "D" be the corner diagonal to the start corner.

a) What is the probability that the man stands at corner D after 3 moves?

b) What is the probability that the man stands at corner D after 4 moves?

c) On average, how many moves does it take to reach corner D?

Is there any way to do this without counting all the possibilities? I don't really have a strong probabilistic background and don't really have any idea how to attack this problem.

Comment: Please edit your question to tell us more about your thinking, what you've tried, and where you're stuck.  This will help people give useful answers at an appropriate level.  (Offhand this problem strikes me as the kind of exercise that assumes the student is comfortable setting up equations that describe expected values.  Have you tried anything along those lines?)

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question in part c) of the average time until arriving at the end vertex, I will slightly modify the statement of the problem to say "He will stand still and no longer move once he reaches corner D."  This will allow us to answer the question of "How long until he arrives at corner D."

Consider instead of specific vertices of the cube, the four different states described by their distance to corner D.  Distance 0, distance 1, distance 2, and distance 3.  Consider the cube with the associated transition diagram on the right between the different states.

[image]

This problem then is best described using Markov Chains with the transition matrix with order 0, 1, 2, 3:

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & \frac{1}{3} & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & \frac{2}{3} & 0\\ 0 & \frac{2}{3} & 0 & 1\\ 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{3} & 0\end{bmatrix}$$

Where the $i^{th}$ row, $j^{th}$ column entry is the probability of moving from state $j$ to state $i$.

This is of the form $\begin{bmatrix} I & S\\ 0 & R\end{bmatrix}$ and the limiting matrix is then $\begin{bmatrix} I & S(I-R)^{-1}\\0 & R\end{bmatrix}$.  The limiting matrix will tell you approximately what percent of the time you will end in a specific absorbing state (one of the states which does not let anything leave it once entered), and for this example is quite uninteresting.  It will be $\begin{bmatrix}1&1&1&1\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$, but the **fundamental matrix** $(I-R)^{-1}$ will tell us all we need to know about expected duration of time until entering *an* absorbing state.

$(I-R)^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix} 3 & 3 & 3\\ 3 & \frac{9}{2} & \frac{9}{2} \\ 1 & \frac{3}{2} & \frac{5}{2}\end{bmatrix}$

To interpret this, we have a 100% chance of starting in state 3, so we add the third column together for a total of $3+\frac{9}{2} + \frac{5}{2} = 10$

More information on this method here [Wikipedia: Absorbing Markov Chains](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorbing_Markov_chain)

It is of interest to note that you could answer parts a and b with these same tools, by first reverting the change away from "once he visits corner D he stays put" to the original interpretation of that he can still move away from corner D after having arrived.

The matrix is then $A=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & \frac{1}{3} & 0 & 0\\ 1 & 0 & \frac{2}{3} & 0\\ 0 & \frac{2}{3} & 0 & 1\\ 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{3} & 0\end{bmatrix}$

To answer parts a and b, look at the first row fourth column entries of $A^3$ and $A^4$ respectively.  In general, the $i^{th}$ row, $j^{th}$ column entry of $A^n$ is the probability of arriving at state $i$ from state $j$ after $n$ steps.

Answer (score 2):

For part $a$ note that the first moves are all symmetrical. After the first move, two out of the three possibilities will land you next to the destination. To get to the destination there is then just one possible move.

So the answer is $\frac 23 \times \frac 13=\frac 29$

For the third part, divide the vertices into four groups - $V_0$ the destination, $V_1$ vertices adjacent to the destination, $V_2$ vertices distance two from the destination and $V_3$ the starting vertex. Let $D_0=0, D_1, D_2, D_3$ be the respective expected path lengths.

We have $D_0=0$.

Making a move from $V_1$ lands us at the destination with probability one third and at some $V_2$ with probability two thirds.

(*)$D_1=1+\frac 23 D_2$

Similarly a move from $V_2$ gives us (**)$D_2=1+\frac 23 D_1+\frac 13 D_3$

And a move from $V_3$ gives $D_3=1+D_2$

To find $D_3$ substitute $D_2=D_3-1$ in (*) and (**) to get (on clearing fractions)

$$3D_1=3+2(D_3-1)=1+2D_3: 6D_1=4D_3+2$$

$$3(D_3-1)=3+2D_1+D_3: 2D_1=2D_3-6: 6D_1=6D_3-18$$

Whence $D_3=10, D_2=9, D_1=7$

Answer (score 1):

You certainly don't need probability for (b) -- rather you need to spot an invariant and check if 4 moves obey this invariant.

In general, note that you have a well-defined distance: every vertex is at distance 1, 2 or 3 from the start vertex, so you can write easily a formula for $T_d(n)$ = the probability that you are at distance $d$ at time $n$ in terms of $T_j(n-1)$ for $j\neq i$. Note that there is just the opposite vertex at distance 3.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: For (a), count how many ways there are to reach D in 3 moves, and then divide by the total number of ways to make 3 moves. For (b), note that if you make 4 moves then at least one move is in the opposite direction of one of your other 3 moves. So can you reach D at all in exactly 4 moves?

Update: The comments show how to calculate the number of ways to reach $D$ in 3 moves. To count the total number of paths of exactly 3 moves, note that no matter what corner of the cube you are at, you always have 3 choices for which corner to visit next.

Comment: I have found 8 ways to get there in 3 but I have no idea how to find the total.

Comment: I don't believe 8 is the correct answer. How many choices do you have for the first move? How many choices for the second? How many choices for the third?

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean, I used a pen and followed until I got to the opposite corner and counted that as a turn

Comment: @user2850514 Then you overcounted.  Brute forcing a count by physically checking each case frequently (as in this case) leads to a mistake.

Comment: How do I use a formula then?

Comment: You can analytically solve it via multiplication principle.  To leave the start vertex, you have three options.  From there, you have two options which continue you in the correct direction (the third option takes you back to start).  From there, you only have one choice in order to get to the end.  Regardless which specific choices were made, the number of choices will always be 3,2,1 at each step respectively, and each selection of choices leads to a distinct path.  Hence, there are only 6 paths.

Answer (score 0):

Let these two square be a 2 dimensional representation of the cube with S being the starting corner and D being the diagonal corner, and integers referring to other corners

```
S - 1
|   |
3 - 2

5 - 4
|   |
6 - D
```

Just by how cubes work, from the starting corner, we can only reach the odd numbered corners(and S) with an odd number of moves and the even numbered corners(and D) with an even number of moves.

Because at each step, you are faced with 3 choices, the number of possibilities with n moves is $3^n$. Just as a general probability rule, we are trying to find:
a) P(D|N=3)
What we observe is that after 1st move, the man can be at corners 1, 3, and 5 with probability of 1/3.
After the 2nd move, the man can be at S with probability 1/3 and 2, 4, and 6 with probability 2/9.
We know that you can only reach D from 2, 4 and 6 with probability 1/3, so the P(D|N=4) = P(2,4,6|N=3) * 1/3 = 2/3*1/3 = 2/9.
b) P(D|N=4)
This is equal to 0 because you cannot reach D with an even number of moves